# How to determine the expected distribution of the population?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I have a sample with a size n = 30. I know the mean and standard deviation of the sample. I also know the distribution of the sample which is normal. With this data, is it possible to determine the expected distribution of 12,000 samples?

Comment: what do you mean be the distribution of multiple samples? I mean, you write that you know the mean and variance and gaussianity, therefore you already know the EXACT distribution.

Comment: @AlbertParadek I just know those details of one sample, not the population or other samples.

Comment: Then how do you want to infer anything about the other samples, if all of your information is about the first sample and not the rest of them? What information do you have on the other samples?

Comment: From your small sample, you can _estimate_ population $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ but maybe not very well. The larger sample will estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ with much better precision. Once you have results from the large sample, it seems the small sample is (almost) irrelevant. // Can you give some more information about the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for your reply. I also know the 30 values (or the data points) of the sample. So, I used qqplot and one-sample kolmogorov-smirnov test to see if the sample comes from a normal distribution. And the test results show that sample is most likely come from a normal distribution.

Comment: @BruceET By the way, what is the expression to calculate the population standard deviation using the sample standard deviation and sample size. I am really confused. Some website say, the relation is Sigma_population = Sigma_sample*sqrt(sample_size). But, based on the expressions for Sigma_population and sigma_sample, I get a relation something like, Sigma_population = Sigma_sample*sqrt((sample_size-1)/sample_size).